# I am thinking of creating a Magento extension and would like to share my idea. Is it possible?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

We've orocrm which is based on CRM. So, I am thinking of developing an extension similar to it in which;
I will pick the database records (which is given in my Magento database) and perform analysis on it. The analysis would be an algorithm based on data mining. So, is it possible to create such an extension?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,it is possible to create such an extension.  However, if you had to ask if it was possible to create such an extension, you probably don't have the necessary abilities or knowledge to easily create that extension.